# Is it possible to continuosly create variables through a loop?

Tags: java, variables, loops, for-loop

For example, if I was to create an int a, then the loop would then create an int b and so forth until it was stopped.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: You can't dynamically name variables in Java.

Comment: Is an *array* perhaps what you are thinking of?

Comment: Why not just use an array or a List?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in a way. You can create multiple objects in a loop, but you can't create actual variables. If the variables already exist then you can work with that through reflection, but I would never advise this.

I'll get ahead of your question though: you can't dynamically decide on the name you'll give these variables.

What you should do is create a collection and store all your variables in there.

If you really want to link a name to a value you can use a `Map<String, Object>` instead of using the dynamic variable name, otherwise an array or an `ArrayList` will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could dynamically name variables, if the language does block scoping (like most common ones) then that specific variable would only exist for the duration of that loop iteration.  Since it won't exist in the next loop iteration, you might as well just use the same name for every iteration.

As other people are saying, if you are trying to store a new value on each iteration you should use an array or list.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a sort of list of variables... You can do that with an `ArrayList` for example. At each iteration, you can add a new element in a list:

```
 ArrayList<Integer> results = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      // your loop, here I just stored the iteration index multiplied by 2
      results.add(i*2);
 }
```

Alternatively, you can create a `HashMap` if you want to give a "name" to each results. The global idea is to create a collection and append every result in it. It'll be accessible after by iterating over the collection created.